# Academia self-evaluation: let's get critical!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, quality-evaluation

You love your site and we love your site, but there is a whole world of people out there who might not even know it exists. When they do find it, their first impression will either scare them away or keep them around. Given this, let's take a hard look at the questions and answers here and make sure newcomers see the site at its best!

Below you'll find ten questions randomly selected from this site. What do you think about each of them and their answers? Are they the best they can be or can they be improved? Would they look interesting and inviting to an outsider or are they a little embarrassing?

Upvote the corresponding post here on meta when we're awesome. Downvote when our content just isn't quite up to par.

Oh, and do comment to let everyone know your thoughts and take part in this conversation. :)

Answer (score 7):

[How important are citations when applying for jobs or promotions?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/933/how-important-are-citations-when-applying-for-jobs-or-promotions)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Well-written question, solid answers, not easily google-able.

Comment: Interesting question, good answers.

Comment: The answer must start "it varies", and it invites discussion rather than a single right objective answer. In short, not suited to the StackExchange format.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers - The "SE format" you refer to varies from site to site, and this community has reached a general consensus that [these types of question and answers are acceptable here](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/12/dealing-with-in-my-experience-answers). I wouldn't compare Stack Overflow's closing criterion to this site.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers: For _any_ reasonable question about academia, the correct answer begins "It varies".  By your standard, we should close the site entirely.

Answer (score 4):

[What do principal investigators (PIs) look for in prospective post docs?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1051/what-do-principal-investigators-pis-look-for-in-prospective-post-docs)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Good question, solid answers. +1.

Answer (score 4):

[At what point do you decide to jump into research?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/966/at-what-point-do-you-decide-to-jump-into-research)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: This question is a good question, and the answers–though somewhat opinion-based–are good advice.

Comment: Subjective, the answer must start "it varies", and it invites discussion rather than a single right objective answer. In short, not suited to the StackExchange format.

Comment: See [previous comments](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/12/dealing-with-in-my-experience-answers).

Answer (score 3):

[A major journal in my field is published by Elsevier. How can we move the field to a less objectionable, more open publisher?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1018/a-major-journal-in-my-field-is-published-by-elsevier-how-can-we-move-the-field)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I'm on the fence about this one. It's a political question, which might not be the best to showcase our site, but the question and answers are comprehensive and solid.

Comment: This is more a discussion than a question (the fact that the OP also posted an answer is a good clue).

Comment: @CharlesMorisset: OP's are allowed, and sometimes _encouraged_, to answer their own questions!

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes here, given the large number of upvotes (and _no_ downvotes) on the original post.  (Yes, it's a political question, but politics is an unavoidable aspect of academia.)

Comment: @aeismail Yes, actually, I've answered some of my own questions, so I'm not in good position to criticize it :) My point was more than the way the question/answer was put: "Here is a current hot topic, and here is what I think about it".

Comment: @JeffE Personally, I think this question fits Academia SE, and that's why I didn't downvote it there, but I don't think it represents Academia SE the best, or that it's the first question I would show to a first-time visitor, which is why I downvoted here.

Comment: It invites discussion rather than a single right objective answer. In short, not suited to the StackExchange format.

Answer (score 3):

[How should students approach quals?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1006/how-should-students-approach-quals)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: This question is quite specific to the US system, but that seems like a good question, with good answers.

Answer (score 3):

[Priority of application materials for admission decision](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/958/priority-of-application-materials-for-admission-decision)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: The title isn't even a question - that's a pretty bad start

Answer (score 3):

[Data publication basics - where, why, how, and when should I publish my unpublished data?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/987/data-publication-basics-where-why-how-and-when-should-i-publish-my-unpublis)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score 3):

[Can a researcher get his full salary from a European Project?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1004/can-a-researcher-get-his-full-salary-from-a-european-project)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Well, I actually found the answer to this question very recently, and I'm going to put the answer. I can't objectively tell if it's a good question, but at least, it was a genuine one :)

Comment: Very helpful. These kind of rules are very often buried deep in 100s of pages of documentation. A nice concise answer like this one is really helpful.

Comment: +1 Finally, a question that actually has an objectively correct answer

Answer (score 2):

[Interview strategies for faculty positions - to focus on their research or your own?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/946/interview-strategies-for-faculty-positions-focus-on-their-research-or-your-own)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score 1):

[Considerations when negotiating a promotion from postdoc to researcher?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/963/considerations-when-negotiating-a-promotion-from-postdoc-to-researcher)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Good answer, but the question highlights the difficulty here with differences in practice across disciplines.