# Academia needs YOU: community evaluation

Tags: discussion, quality-evaluation

A new section has appeared in the [list of review queues](https://academia.stackexchange.com/review): ***[community evaluation](https://academia.stackexchange.com/review/community-eval)***. It is temporary, and will stay for a few days. It is the new form of the older [self-evaluation](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/123/2700).

If you open it, you will be asked to evaluate 10 relatively recent questions from the site, with the following criteria:

> Review the question and its answers and compare them to information available from other online sources. What type of impression would this question make on a first-time visitor to the site? Are the answers correct, clear, useful and informative? **Would the question and answer be interesting to the kind of user this site is trying to attract, or are they a little embarrassing?**

The review can help us (SE team, mods and community) gauge the attractiveness to new users. So, let's all chip in!

Comment: Done. Question now closed. Should we delete?

Comment: Other metas usually keep such time-limited questions around, only closed. I have no opinion on the matter.